# php svn class svn_fs_make_dir ( resource $root , string $path )

Tags: php, svn, release-management

I am trying to write a class to handle svn. Looking at php website looks like there are some functions already there but, have problem using them since not enough documentations.

Has anyone worked with svn_fs_make_dir ( resource $root , string $path )? if so what is "resource $root". I can't figure it out.

Does anyone know a good open source php class to deal with svn requests? I am doing a release management project and need to access svn within the code and create, copy,...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least [phpsvnclient](http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/) *documented* better, know nothing about it's quality

Comment: I have tried that but, it doesn't have all functionalities I need. Thanks